# Blazor Component Lifecycle - How do you do something async in the component after parameters are set but before they bind

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Dialog Component that pops up to edit a row of a grid.

When you click the row, I set a `selectedItem` variable which is bound to a parameter of my dialog component and make the dialog visible.

```html
<MyDialog @bind-MyObject="selectedItem" @bind-Visible="dialogVisible" />
```

The problem is the MyDialog component needs to get a property from `selectedItem` then make an async call to an API and load some data before the `selectedItem` binds to all the fields in the dialog.

If I make my API call in `OnParametersSetAsync()`, it is too late, the `selectedItem` is already bound.

If I try to use `SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)`, you get an error if you try to do something async before calling the base implementation which binds the parameter.

This seems like a fairly normal scenario, is there another approach here?

Comment: Instead of binding the `Visible` property, I'd put the entire `<MyDialog>` object in a conditional: `@if(dialogueVisible) { <MyDialog. . . >}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditionally show the bound elements:

```
@if (_ready)
{
    <label>@MyObject.SomeProperty</label>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public MyClass MyObject { get; set; }

    // Do not create elements bound to parameter until I say
    bool _ready = false;   

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        await MyApi.GetSomeMoreData();
        // Done what I need to do, you can render the bound elements now
        _ready = true;   
    }
}
```

Comment: ah good idea, that solves my problem, thanks